# How can I convert boundaries when integrating with trigonometric substitution?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I am attempting to evaluate the integral $$\int_0^{\frac{1}{6}}\frac{x^5}{(36x^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\text{d}x\,\,\,.$$ Part of the solution is shown in the below image:

[image]

I understand how to substitute the $x$-value, but down at the bottom of the image, when it converts the boundaries $a=0$ and $b=\frac{1}{6}$ to radians, where the hell does the $1$ come from for the upper bound?

The way I understand the conversion is that to get radians or $\theta$, I just get the inverse of whatever trigonometric substitution I used for $x$ with the boundaries as inputs.

Comment: It comes from solving $\frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{6} \sec^2 \theta$ for $\theta$.

Comment: why am i evaluating it with sec^2 instead of tan?

Comment: actually now i understand what the textbook meant. so b = 1/6 tan theta so basically i need to find 1=tan theta which is pi/4